# Hibernate Search poor performance when calling FullTextQueryImpl.getResultList()

Tags: performance, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm developing a web app using hibernate search 4.4.

I am having performance issue when calling *getResultList()* of *FullTextQuery*.

The generated query executes in about 30 milliseconds, but the entire method takes about 1 second to execute.

The query will return a small set; about 15 items.

Does anyone have any idea about what could cause this poor performance or how to improve or fix this.

If you need any other informations please leave a comment so I can add it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Regarding to some subject googling, could using custom resultTransformer improove performance ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description it looks like the Lucene Query is fast but the database load is slow.

The *FullTextQuery* normally performs two phases:
 - execute the Lucene Query
 - load the results from the Database

Unless you are using projections: in that case the results are loaded from the index and you avoid loading from the Database.
So you could [use projections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.4/reference/en-US/html_single/#projections) to entirely avoid hitting the database, or at least to confirm that this hypothesis of the database loading being slow is correct.

If that's confirmed, you'll need to improve the loading performance from the database; you should enable SQL Logging from Hibernate ORM to see if the generated queries are unnecessarily complex, for example the loaded entity might have too many relations marked as eager loading? Or maybe the kind of queries you need could be helped with an index on the database schema.

Alternatively you can look into enabling second level caching, in these cases it might be particularly effective to look for *ManyToOne* relations, where the "One" side has a limited amount of total different entities in the database.

An advice on Hibernate ORM general-purpose performance: try to use the most recent version you can as the latest versions benefit from exceptional performance improvements.

Comment: Hi @Sanne, thank you for your response and suggestions. I'm not using projection, I'll try to change my code to use it and give you a performance status feedback.

Comment: Thank you for your answear, it improoved performance and let me see other bottlenecks. I'm still profiling my app  :)

Comment: getResultList() of FullTextQuery cold call was about 800 ms now it is about 10 ms :)